# Does anyone have a descriptive list of prize bubble locations?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I can find several [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) videos of people going through each level in [LittleBigPlanet 2](http://www.littlebigplanet.com/en/2/) showing where Prize Bubbles are located. Are there any just plain ***lists*** of where they are? I've been through some of the levels already and have only a few bubbles I still need. It would be much easier for me to have a short description of where the groups of prize bubbles are instead of having to play, pause, play, pause, skip forward, skip backwards, etc. a [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) video trying to follow along for the one prize bubble I'm missing (not to mention having to indulge the creator's terrible sense of humor which is apparently the standard for any gaming videos on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com)).

The closest thing I've found is on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/954843-littlebigplanet-2/faqs/61926), but that is a full description of how to beat each level. I'd love to have just a quick sentence for each prize bubble or group of prize bubbles describing their locations. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a full link to levels:](http://guides.ign.com/guides/19675/page_3.html)

- Da Vinci's Hideout
- Victoria's Laboratory
- The Factory of a Better Tomorrow
- Avalonia
- Eve's Asylum
- The Cosmos

Hope this is what you are looking for.

It provides quick segments for each bubble and prize location once you click on the desired world.